# How to update running kafka connector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, dcos

I have kafka conenct running in Marathon container. If I want to update the connector plugin (jar) I have to upload the new one and then restart the Connect task.

Is it possible to do that without restarting/downtime?

Answer (score 1):

The updated jar for the connector plugin needs to be added to the classpath and then the classloader for the worker needs to pick it up.  The best way to do this currently is to take an outage as described [here](http://docs.confluent.io/3.1.0/connect/managing.html#upgrading-a-connector-plugin).

Depending on your connector, you might be able to do rolling upgrades, but the generic answer is that if you need to upgrade the connector plugin, you currently have to take an outage.

Comment: To add to this, the vast majority of connectors will be fine with a rolling upgrade. So in many cases if you have Connect running in distributed mode no downtime will be required. However, as @dawsaw says, this is dependent on the connector being written in a compatible fashion (and not just backwards compatible since during the upgrade assignments might switch between old and new versions of the connector).